# Can you not use function variables inside another function's associated code?

Tags: javascript

In the code exercise at Codecademy[1], it asks you to cube a variable and I can easily do that using:

```
// Accepts a number x as input and returns its square
function square(x) {
  return x * x;
}

// Accepts a number x as input and returns its cube
function cube(x) {
  return x * x * x;
}

cube(7);
```

My question is for the cube function, why do I get a `NaN` error when I use the following code instead:

```
function cube(x) {
  return x * square;
}
```

[1] http://www.codecademy.com/courses/functions_in_javascript/0#!/exercise/1

Comment: Because you cannot multiply a number with a function (what result do you expect?). The function object, represented as number, is `NaN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try :

you missed `(x)`

```
function cube(x) {
  return x * square(x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
function cube(x) {
    return x * square(x);
}
```

x * square will attempt to multiply x with a function which causes the problem

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `square` is resolved as a function. And to get the returned value, you need to *invoke* the function instead just *reference* it.

```
function cube(x) {
  return x * square(x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have a multiplication or division operation, both arguments are first [converted to numbers](http://es5.github.com/#x11.5). Functions don't have a reasonable conversion so they are converted to NaN.

```
Number(function(){}) //gives NaN
```

And if you multiply anything by NaN you also get NaN

```
2 * NaN
1 * (function(){}) //also gives NaN since the function is converted to that
```

The solution (as many mentioned) is multiplying by the square of x instead of by the square function itself.

```
x * square(x)
```